# Support Beam for 14 ppt span

Tags: structural, support, beam

I have a 14 foot span that is load bearing on 1st floor, 2x8 joists. What is needed to support the weight on this cape in connecticut.

Answer (score 2):

While Ecnerwal is probably right, a little expansion is appropriate here.

You'll probably need a steel beam to hold it up. You can take a stab at a laminated beam, but steel is the gold standard because a steel I-beam holds far more than a laminated beam.

If it were my house, I'd make sure I get it right because if you don't the cost of repairs could be far more than a steel beam. Or a structural engineer.

Answer (score -1):

The structural analysis of an engineer licensed to practice in Connecticut.